# Confused on one ActiveX registering issue

Tags: c++, windows, activex, ocx

I got one CommDev ActiveX project compiled on both 32 bit os and 64 bit os. Now I have CommDev_x86.ocx and CommDev_x64.ocx. Here comes the problem on Windows 7 os. Should I put CommDev_x86.ocx at C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and CommDev_x64.ocx at C:\Windows\System32, and then execute "regsvr32  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CommDev_x86.ocx" and "regsvr32  C:\Windows\System32\CommDev_x64.ocx"?  Should I register all of them or just one of them? For that I found there exists both 32bit IE and 64 bit IE on the os.Can anyone do me a favor? Thanks.

Comment: There are two distinct versions of Regsvr32.exe.  The one in c:\windows\system32 should be used to register the 64-bit server, the one in c:\windows\syswow64 should be used to register the 32-bit server.  Whether you actually should build and register both is up to you to figure out, we can't tell what software is used by your clients.  Since you probably don't know either, it can't hurt to support both.  Well, assuming you tested that.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! I am aware of those two versions of Regsvr32 and I have used them separately already. Thanks all the same! However, when I checked register of the os I found the default value of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{"clsid"}\InprocServer32 is C:\Windows\SysWow64\CommDev_x86.ocx. So has CommDev_x64.ocx been registed successfully yet?